# Почему скрипты при подключении из файлов могут не работать?

Tags: javascript, html

Раньше у меня на сайте JSы были прямо в HTML-документе, решил их переписать в файлы и подключить с помощью тега <script>, теперь некоторые скрипты не работают. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему?

Comment: теперь и я не могу коментировать к ответу, может дополни вопрос кодами как было и как стало?

Comment: ссылку пожалуйста посмотрите (исходный код большой, пишет осталось -2500 символов :D):
http://PofL.ucoz.ru/photo.html
меню кстати там тоже кривое - в опере нормально, а в хроме отступ 24px (написал margin-top: 0px), если напишу margin-top: -24px, то в опере не будет видно пол меню.

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" src="/horisontalmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script language="JavaScript" src="/Photo/ext-core-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    
сначала подрубаешь свой скрипт, а потом библиотеку, при этом у меня твоя библиотека приходит пустой, именно в этом проблема  
  
и ещё один момент: language="JavaScript" - это убери, оно лишнее, тк ты указываешь type="text/javascript"

Comment: спасибо большое!) как же я сам не догадался)))
ещё можно вопрос? в JS margin-top как будет? так же?

Comment: нет, немного не так  
document.getElementById('qwe').style.marginTop = '20px';

Comment: спасибо <script> if(navigator.appName = Netscape) { document.getElementById(menu).marginTop='-24px'; } </script> а здесь есть ошибки? почему-то он у меня не работает...

Comment: @SurPaul, а вы через NetScape/Mozilla сидите?

Comment: @Construct, да, Google Chrome

Comment: @SurPaul, попробуй

    if (navigator.appName == Netscape) 
     {
      document.getElementById('menu').marginTop='-24px';
     }

То есть __'menu'__ в кавычках, т.к. строка и == (сравнение), а не = (присваивание).

Comment: @SurPaul ты забыл про style перед marginTop, если конечно в нетскейпе оно не опускается, тут точно не знаю, потому как я некрофилией не страдаю, не наслаждаюсь и вам не советую  
вообще в таком случае как у тебя, ты по-идее задаёшь атрибу margin-top, в то время как надо менять стиль

Comment: @RedMonkey, значение 'netscape' в navigator.appName означает ещё и браузер Google Chrome.

Comment: Вы бы лучше через класс указывали. т.е добавляем класс, а в css уже пишем: margin-top: -24px;

Answer (score 2):

вероятнее всего из-за того что ты выставляешь события на объекты из js когда структура дома не сформировалась, попробуй использовать для выставление событий:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('qwe').onclick = function(){
        // ..код функции
    }
}
```

либо функции "домреди" если используешь фреймворки

Comment: ну понятно... что ничего не понятно... нужно учить js))

Comment: проще говоря ты присваиваешь действие когда элемента ещё нет, можешь скинуть кусок кода который после перестаёт работать, тогда на конкретном примере поясню

Comment: @SurPaul, попробую на понятном вам языке объяснить ))) В вашем html-документе вякие тэги понаписаны. Так вот, может такая бяда случиться, когда JS-скрипт уже начинает выполнятся, а эти теги, собаки, еще загрузиться не успели и JS их просто не увидит. И **RedMonkey** предлагает вам способ, уговорить JS подождать, пока эти ленивые теги подгрузятся. Вот )))

Comment: Ext.onReady(function() {
new Ext.ux.Menu('simple-horizontal-menu', {
transitionType: 'slide',
direction: 'horizontal',
delay: 0.2,
autoWidth: true,
transitionDuration: 0.3,
animate: true,
currentClass: 'current'
});
new Ext.ux.Menu('simple-vertical-menu', {
direction: 'vertical'
});
});

(из примеров библиотеки ext-core)
виноват вроде этот скрипт

Comment: ну тут вроде есть событие домреди, тогда возможно что ты вначале подрубаешь свои скрипты и только потом библиотеку Ext, скинь логи хрома, будет ещё понятнее в чём дело

Comment: какие логи? хрома (браузера)? а я через оперу...

Comment: в опере фигово разрабатывать, ставть google chrome(браузер)

Comment: не могу ещё раз ответить, посему пишу сюда.  
Ext is not defined horisontalmenu.js:1 - говорится что объект Ext не объявлен, поэтому оно и не может его применить, иными словами ты определённо либо не подрубаешь библиотеку, либо, что более вероятно, подрубаешь скрипт свой скрипт до библиотеки, и посему он её не видит

Comment: а почему вы можете оставлять ещё комменты, а я нет? из-за "рейтинга"?)
вопрос: почему раньше всё работало нормально, а когда переписал в файл и подключил с помощью тега - ошибки появились, я так думал что разницы никакой не должно быть... так даже M3C рекомендует делать...

Comment: @SurPaul, вам же ответили, возможно, что тег с вашим скриптом стоит до тега со скриптом фреймворка. А надо наоборот.